# Integrating Google Pay into website using OmniChannel APIs

Tags: java

https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/otherapis/omnichannel/overview 
This is the documentation provided. I'm stuck in a step where you call Google tokens API and receive response token to call Omnichannel APIs.

https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN));

Using Google Client Library for Java, credential object should return the access token for calling the OmniChannel APIs, but its returning null.

In Collections, I'm supposed to provide the scope for which Google API I want to use. It is NBU Payments Merchants API , but I cant find on Google API console. 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/nbupaymentsmerchants

Comment: can you post error logs here? so that others can help.

Comment: The thing is I'm not getting any error. I get back the credential object. But when I call credential.getAccessToken(), I get null value.